# How can I convert HTML to PDF using Perl?

Tags: html, perl, pdf

I need to convert some HTML reports into PDF using Perl. What are the best [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) modules for the job?

Comment: It depends a bit if you need support for CSS. Most of the solutions only support very basic HTML 3.0 or so and little or no CSS.

Comment: Try wkhtmltopdf - http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf
It's a console HTML->PDF converter, it also supports CSS styles.

Answer (score 7):

I hope [PDF::FromHTML](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::FromHTML) may be of help.

Comment: is this available for Windows... running Perl on Windows

Comment: Yes it runs on Windows as well. Reference: [CPAN Testers](http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/P/PDF-FromHTML.html).

Comment: No CSS for you! _CAVEATS: [...] This means any HTML using external or inline CSS for design and layout, including but not limited to: images, backgrounds, colours, fonts etc... will not be converted into the PDF._.

Answer (score 3):

[HTML::HTMLDoc](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::HTMLDoc) uses the underlying htmldoc C library which is built to do just this. And it's pretty fast too.

Comment: As of September 2011, only the development (beta) version 1.9 supports HTML 4.0 and CSS partially. However it does appear well designed and documented.

Answer (score 3):

### [PDF::WebKit](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::WebKit)

I could convert from HTML to PDF with Perl with PDF::WebKit, which in turn uses [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/). From `apt show wkhtmltopdf`:

> Command line utilities to convert html to pdf or image using WebKit wkhtmltopdf is a command line program which permits one to create a pdf or an image from an url, a local html file or stdin. It produces a pdf or an image like rendered with the WebKit engine.
>
> **This program requires an X11 server to run.**

<strike>Therefore, this solution seems unacceptable on a server. Maybe [WeasyPrint](https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/tree/gh-pages) (built with Python) or [athenapdf](https://github.com/arachnys/athenapdf)? Or [Pandoc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/533888/209677)?</strike>

**The latest version is headless (does not require X server).**

Installation:

```
sudo cpanm install PDF::WebKit
sudo apt install xfonts-75dpi
sudo apt install wkhtmltopdf
```

[Use .deb from official site](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html#stable) to get the latest version.

**html2pdf.pl**

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use PDF::WebKit;
my $kit = PDF::WebKit->new('/tmp/index.html');
my $file = $kit->to_file('/tmp/my.pdf');
```

Sample, **index.html**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>My Title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <p class="text-primary">.text-primary</p>
  <p class="text-secondary">.text-secondary</p>
  <p class="text-success">.text-success</p>
  <p class="text-danger">.text-danger</p>
  <p class="text-warning">.text-warning</p>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I've used [PDF::API2](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::API2) to create PDF reports with great success.

Comment: PDF::API2 is very powerful, but it requires pixel-level addresses for layout -- not good for easily formatting text.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on exactly what you need to do, but I'd probably look at [Template::Extract](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Template::Extract) and [PDF::Template](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/PDF::Template).

Answer (score 1):

[PinceXML](http://www.princexml.com/)

That doesn't answer you question in the sense of using Perl, but as far as I know that is the best HTML to PDF converter available.

Comment: I've heard good things about it too. It does document using it from Perl ( http://www.princexml.com/doc/6.0/perl/ ) but that just boils down to "Use STDIN/SDOUT".

Comment: PrinceXML appears to support CSS well (one of the authors helped draft the original CSS specification) but it costs quite a lot for commercial use. They also provide a CSS example file for pagination of HTML/XML documents and formatting books.

Comment: I work at Expected Behavior, and we've got an HTML to PDF API called DocRaptor that uses Prince as the rendering engine for PDFs. Our service is a good way of getting the quality of Prince without doing a server-side installation. http://docraptor.com

Comment: We have been using PrinceXML at my company for a while, and it is absolutely amazing. Sure, it is not free or cheap, but much cheaper than trying to build it all yourself.